# Why does my navigation open behind the body

Tags: javascript, html, css

Topnav is the navigation bar. I've also included other parts of the website like the about section for my portfolio, so it shows more code than what is required.

I'm trying to make my menu pop out when I click the burger icon button. What is currently happening is that the home, about, and contact button hides, and the burger icon replaces that but the menu isn't popping when I click the burger icon.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("homee");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90vh;
  background-image: url(white.jpeg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: Black;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: tahoma;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  float: right
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav-right {
  float: left;
}


/*RESPONSIVE*/

.topnav a {
  display: none;
}

.topnav a.icon {
  float: right;
  display: block;
}

.topnav.responsive {
  position: relative;
}

.topnav.responsive a.icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.topnav.responsive a {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}


/*RESPONSIVE*/

.llin {
  border: 0px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.textcon p:nth-child(1) {
  font-family: Calibri;
  line-height: 1px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  font-size: 120%;
  margin-top: -30%;
  margin-left: 23%;
}

.textcon p:nth-child(2) {
  font-family: Calibri;
  padding: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 300%;
  line-height: 1em;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  margin-left: 23%;
}

.textcon p:nth-child(3) {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: black;
  font-size: 120%;
  margin: 0;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 100%;
  margin-left: 23%;
}

.textcon p {
  line-height: 2%;
  margin-left: 13%;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
}

.textcon {
  position: absolute;
  left: 17%;
  top: 42%;
  transform: translate(-13%, -42%);
  width: 80%;
  height: 1%;
}

.textcon button {
  width: 50%;
  height: 8vh;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.downcv {
  background-color: #0b0b0b;
  color: white;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="topsec">
  <!---Navigator-->

  <div class="topnav" id="homee">
    <a href="mailto:amakwana@wisc.edu?">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#resume">Resume</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="topnav-right">
      <form action="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ananya-makwana-56989142">
        <button type="submit" class="llin"><img src="linkedin.png" width="50" height="50" alt="submit"/></button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!---TEXT PART-->
  <div class="textcon">
    <p>Hello,</p>
    <p>I'm Ananya Makwana,</p>
    <p>I am a senior senior at University of Wisconsin-Madison majoring in computer science and I'm actively looking for full-time Software Development positions starting May '21.</p>
    <form method="get" action="ResumeAnanya.pdf">
      <button class="downcv" type="submit">Download Resume</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <!---Picture-->
  <div class="textcon">
    <img src="png2.png" class="model" alt="model"></div>
</section>
<!---About-->
<div class="aboutcon" id="about">
  <img src="improved.jpg" class="textwrap" alt="Avatar">
  <div class="abouttext">
    <p>About Me</p>
    <p>Hello, my name is Ananya. I am an extremely enthusiastic person with an interest in Software Development. I have taken a broad range of courses as I am always eager to learn more. I love problem solving and I am also a very creative peron who likes
      to design during my free time.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why does your main content have `position: relative;` and why aren’t you using `z-index`?

Answer (score 0):

Try Giving a z-index value to your  nav.

z-index will place your nav in front of main body of your content.